# Material ui select onchange is not bubbling

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, event-bubbling

I have a div which has a material ui Select, material ui TextField and a plain html select.
This div has an onchange event which simply console logs the *event.target.value*. When ever the onchange of material ui TextField or the select is triggered, *event.target.value* is logged to the console. But not for the onchange of material ui select.

sample code: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-03495?file=/demo.tsx

What am i missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event that triggers the change does bubble, but it is not a "change" event. The `onChange` function that you provide gets called in response to a [click event on the `MenuItem`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.1/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L177). And even that "click" event could either be a click event or a [key down event](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.1/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js#L225) (e.g. if you use arrow keys and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select an item).

Here's a modification of your sandbox with some additional console logging: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-u5b51?file=/demo.tsx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **native** attribute. You will get UI as **Material** but functionality as **native** select and thus bubbles too.

```
      <Select
        native
        value={muiSelectValue}
        onChange={handleMuiSelectOnChange}
        autoWidth
      >
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
      </Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything. If you add `console.log(event)` in your handle change functions, you will get to know that events of native elements are `syntheticEvents` where event you'll get in MUI's handle change will be a `class` as object. Hence whenever you change the value it will not get reflected to your actual div.